# Use Android ListView from Superclass

Tags: android, listview, inheritance

I'd like to inherit two classes (one of them: "AuthenticateRoomSelectionActivity") from another class ("RoomSelectionBaseActivity"), because I have two activities in an Android app, which are going to be quite similar. They consist of a Constraint Layout, which holds some Buttons, TextViews and (most important) an ListView.

I would like to implement the ArrayAdapter in the Superclass, because the Data-Input is exactly the same. So I implemented a setRoomList() method, which is called back, after some networking is done in another class:

```
public void setRoomList(Activity activity, ArrayList<Room> roomList) {
    // Save rooms to instance variable
    this.roomList = roomList;

    // Populate roomListView
    ArrayAdapter<Room> roomAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<>(activity, R.layout.list_row_layout, roomList);
    roomListView.setAdapter(roomAdapter);
}
```

In the onCreate() method of the inherited class I call the networking method getAllRooms().

```
// Get all rooms
    RestProvider.getInstance().getAllRooms(this);
```

The RestProvider-method collects network data with Retrofit 2:

```
    public void getAllRooms(final RoomSelectionBaseActivity activity) {
    Call<ArrayList<Room>> call = mRestAPI.getAllRooms(Session.getInstance().getBearer());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Room>>() {

        // Set room list in activity
        @Override public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Room>> call, Response<ArrayList<Room>> response) {
            activity.setRoomList(activity, response.body());
        }

        // Show error messages in activity
        @Override public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Room>> call, Throwable t) {
            activity.showToast("ERROR: " + t.getMessage());
            Log.v("REST-Error: ", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

...and even passes the context's reference to the context, to make sure, it really uses the right context in setRoomList().

I'm totally stuck with this architecture, because there is no ListView shown, when I call AuthenticateRoomSelectionActivity.

Additional info: The whole layout is inherited from RoomSelectionBaseActivity as well. This is my activity_authenticate_room_selection.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="de.hhn.mim.vs.roomfactorclient.activities.roomselection.AuthenticateRoomSelectionActivity">

    <include
            layout="@layout/activity_room_selection"
            android:id="@+id/activity_room_selection_include"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!
Best,
Nils

Comment: just to check.. the response.body() is not null or size 0 right?

Comment: No, networking works fine. I printed the response.body() to Log.